# Database: How to make my shopping database to have products with various sizes, specs, categories, grades etc?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am designing an online shopping database, however for a specific set of products. The products has the following.

1. Product Species
2. Product Category
3. Product Type
4. Product Grade
5. Product Size

Below is my database diagram

[image]

In the application, when we select the **Product Species**, we will be taken to a page where we have to do other selections. In this page there is a dropdown, where we have to select the **Product Category**. Then the relevant list of **Product Types** will get loaded. Then select the **Product Type**, the relevant list of Product Grades will get loaded. Now you can select the product size.

Below is the UI of the applications selection page

[image]

**HERE THE "C/T" MEANS "CATEGORY AND TYPE"**

With my database design, I find it difficult to perform the "selection operation" in the app itself. To load the `fresh products` after selecting the `product species` I can simply call `select * from fresh_products where idproduct_species=1`. But then, how can I find the **Product Grades** by selecting a **C/T**? How can I find the **Product Spec** by selecting the **Product Grade**?

I know I can run some quarries in the `fresh_products` table and get this done, even though it won't be easy as a `select` statement.

If you are interested, below I have shared the product sheet, with dummy information.

[image]

To achieve what I need, is my database design a good one or is there a better model?

Comment: `it won't be easy as a select statement` ... your current database design more or less looks good, and to answer your business questions, you are going to have to join to the other tables.  Those queries can be optimized as well if needed.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Thank you. I am not sure what you meant by `join to other tables`. You mean `join` queries? In this case, which tables to be specific? Can give an example please?

Comment: You are the one who needs to describe the example use case.  I sense you are not expert working with databases (despite your high rep), but the problem you described is fairly common, and your current design is OK.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I am not saying I am an expert. Every time I design a database, I try to make it better than my earlier one. I know you meant join with tables such as `grades`, `specs` etc. But I was wondering whether there is something we can do in design level to ease the selection process, reducing no of code lines. otherwise i have to scan the same `fresh_products` for `grades`, `specs` etc with somewhat complex queries or codes.

Comment: As mentioned, the model looks sensible. If you have a problem with constructing a specific query (or range of queries), see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Also, 'NPM' ? nano-particulate matter?

Comment: @Strawberry: Thank you. A side question, I will be using the following query to load the list of  `specs` to the "spec drop down", when the "C/T" and "Grade" are selected. `SELECT DISTINCT idproduct_specs from fresh_products where idproduct_species=1 AND idproduct_species=34 AND idproduct_category=11`. Any better ideas?

Comment: @Strawberry: Regarding "NPM". No, I just added some dummy data. Typed some coded products in. There is no product as NPM.

Comment: It depends on the size of the database and/or its rate of growth. If it's a fairly small dataset - a couple of thousand products, say, then I would just grab the whole thing, spit it out as json, and handle the filtering with a bit of javascript. For a larger dataset, your approach might be more sensible, but I'd just suck it and see.

Comment: You may not need so much 'normalization'.  That is, a single table may be good enough -- unless you have other reasons for the 5 tables.

Comment: @RickJames Yes. This is to prevent the staff from entering whatever the thing they want into this database. They have a list of size, species, types, grades etc. Anything else other than the things defined by the company should not be inserted.

Comment: @PeakGen - What action should be taken when the staff enters a 'bad' value?  (I am fishing for whether to talk about `CHECK`, error messages, `TRIGGERs`, application code instead of database code, etc.)

Comment: @PeakGen - `where species=1 AND category=11` -- Wouldn't you prefer to say `where species='Fish' AND category='BK29'`.  Once you try to write something like that, you end up with multiple `JOINs` and performance suffers.  Manually turning 'Fish' into 1 involves more code and slower operations.

Comment: @RickJames: Well, in their Dashboard, they can select instead of inserting values. For an example, the "Size" dropdown will load the authorized sizes from the `Size` table. So they can't insert a bad value. Then, who supply the data into the `size` table? The admin, who is responsible for getting things done.

Comment: @RickJames: Regarding your comment about `Joins`, well, I agree. But what to do? I have to first think of how to stop unwanted data.

Comment: @PeakGen - Check out `ENUM`.  That datatype is implemented as a small number, but is inserted/selected as a string.  `species ENUM('unknown', 'Fish', 'Horse') NOT NULL` and `WHERE species = 'Fish'`  (There are many pros and cons to `ENUMs`, but it might be best.

Comment: @RickJames MySQL ENUM?

Comment: Search for `mysql enum` -- read the manual and/or a tutorial.